# Why are the variables in my object being reset to the default?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to write a chess clock on an Arduino with an LCD keypad shield. I'm almost completely new to C++ and I think I'm having trouble with how it handles class objects.

In my code I have a menu which should allow players to change the amount of time available to them by pressing the right and left buttons on the keypad. This seems to work at first, but when I switch to the other player and back again using the up and down buttons the `minutes` variable gets reset to the default value of 5 minutes.

What am I missing about how my `Player` objects are being handled?

```
boolean menuActive = true;

class Player {
  // Represents a player.
  public:
    int minutes;              // number of minutes allowed
    void IncrementMinutes();   
    void DecrementMinutes();   
};

void Player::IncrementMinutes() {
  this->minutes += 1;
}

void Player::DecrementMinutes() {
  if (this->minutes > 1) {
    this->minutes -= 1;
  }
}

Player p1 = {5, false, 1, "P1 mins: ", 0};
Player p2 = {5, false, 2, "P2 mins: ", 0};

Player menuPlayer = p1;

void setup()
{
 lcd.begin(16, 2);  
 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print("ChessClock");
}

// Main loop
void loop()
{
 lcd_key = read_LCD_buttons();  
 if (menuActive) {
   switch (lcd_key)               
   {
     case btnRIGHT:
       {
        // increase minutes
        menuPlayer.IncrementMinutes();        
        delay(250);        
        break;
       }  
     case btnLEFT:
       {
        // decrease minutes        
        menuPlayer.DecrementMinutes();        
        delay(250);        
        break;
       }  
     case btnUP:
       {
        // select player 1
        menuPlayer = p1;
        break;
       }  
     case btnDOWN:
       {
        // select player 2
        menuPlayer = p2;
        break;
       }  
     case btnNONE:
       {
       // display the current value for minutes
       lcd.print(menuPlayer.minutes);
       break;       
       }
     }
 } else {
   // Main timer code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a *copy* of your Players:

```
// The actual players
Player p1 = {5, false, 1, "P1 mins: ", 0};
Player p2 = {5, false, 2, "P2 mins: ", 0};

// A COPY of player 1
Player menuPlayer = p1;
```

When you make calls like

```
menuPlayer.IncrementMinutes();
```

You are simply changing `menuPlayer`, not `p1` or `p2`. So when you do the following

```
menuPlayer = p2;
```

All the changes made to `menuPlayer` are lost, and you make a new copy.

You could fix this by copying `menuPlayer` into `p1` before swapping:

```
p1 = menuPlayer;
menuPlayer = p2;
```

Or by making `menuPlayer` a `Player*`:

```
// Point to p1:
Player* menuPlayer = &p1;

// Changes p1
menuPlayer->IncrementMinutes();
```

Comment: Ah, I thought the issue was in that line. Thanks. One more question - how do I switch the `menuPlayer` if it's a pointer? My `btnUP` and `btnDOWN` buttons are giving me the following: `error: cannot convert 'Player' to 'Player*' in assignment
         menuPlayer = p1;`

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I needed to change `menuPlayer = p1;` to `menuPlayer = &p1;` in the `btnUP` function and the same for `p2` and `btnDOWN`.